# How to defend from bot update?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bots

I am guessing this should be already answered on SO but I am a noob, so lacking the proper terminology.
I have a website that lets logged in users to post comments on my articles. Post is pretty straightforward. So creating a script to post data is trivial task. How do I stop users from abusing the system? I am not talking about ddos attack. Just normal script that posts regularly and keeps my server busy.
In my case, user can post or update comment to an article. I am thinking if I should restrict user to n (probably 10) number of times they can update a comment. But how efficient is that?
What are some best way to detect abusing users and how to keep my server unaffected by them?
I know it's not an easy take to do so, but what are the best known practises. My site is hosted on AWS (EC2). Any services they have in place to fix this kind of attacks?

Answer (score 0):

1. don't let new users do everything right at the start, like on SO
2. if you think it's a bot, demand a CAPTCHA value
3. include honeypot (hidden) form fields and disregard input if they are filled in